# Using remark and rehype plugins with nextjs-13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I wanted to try out nextjs-13 so made a very simple blog.

Folder structure (skip to '**The Problem**' section for actual issue):

```
app/
  page.jsx
  layout.jsx
  test.mdx
public/
 ...
styles/
 ...
mdx-components.jsx
next.config.mjs
package.json
```

So this is a pure nextjs-13 app with all content only in the app/ directory.

**next.config.mjs**

```
import nextMDX from "@next/mdx";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";
import rehypePrism from "@mapbox/rehype-prism";

// /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "mdx"],
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    mdxRs: true,
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
};

export default nextMDX({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
    rehypePlugins: [rehypePrism],
  },
})(nextConfig);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    // ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mapbox/rehype-prism": "^0.8.0",
    "@next/mdx": "latest",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "remark-gfm": "^3.0.1",
    "remark-rehype": "^10.1.0",
  },
}
```

and finally, **page.jsx**

```
import Foo from "./test.mdx";

export default function Page() {
  return <Foo />;
}
```

and **layout.jsx**

```
import "./global.scss";
import "../styles/prism.css";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

## The problem

When I run this, next certainly seems to be compiling the mdx. But it's some very basic out-of-the-box transform that does not parse code blocks (all code appears as a single string), and does not render tables correctly. That is, rehypePrism and remarkGfm are not actually being applied.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolved. Disabling `mdxRs` in next.config.js fixed the issue.

```
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "mdx"],
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    mdxRs: false, // <- disabled
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
};
```

Comment: wow, thanks. Had the same issue. Unfortunate this isn't mentioned in the docs.